# Tracking variable assignments in bitbake

Tags: openembedded, bitbake

I'm using bitbake / openembedded, but my recipe fails because some path-variable ends up being not set correctly I think. Specifically i'm adding files to SRC_URI, but the error indicates the attempt to copy the file is done using the wrong path. Therefore

1) How can I verify the "current" path-variable used when using file:// protocol

2) Given that I somehow confirm which variable is used to search for files, can I track assignments to said variable in my dependency-graph? I mean, bitbake must encounter appends/prepends to the variable in some order in some set of recipe-files, which i would like to inspect in order to find my error

Bonus question: I'm thinking that my current "debug-method" for detecting errors in my recipes is too primitive (e.g. adding -D -D -D to the command-line and subsequently wade through the piles of output to look for hints). How do "professionals" debug their bitbake recipes?

**Update:** I've found a much better way of debugging my recipes:

It turns out, that after the "fetch" task of a given recipe has successfully completed, the working folder for the recipe is created. Inside this folder is a "temp" sub-folder containing the code executed (e.g run.do_fetch.######) and the results (e.g. log._do_fetch.######) for each task in the recipe.

Inspecting the "run..###" file will tell you the exact value of any variable, and the exact commands/Python-functions executed for the task. The output of a given "run" is stored in the "log..###" file with same id/number as the "run" file. Somehow this very basic information did not register while I read the manual, but now I always look in the "temp" folder when a recipe fails.

Comment: Re: *"exact value ofany variable"*: I see only environment variables in these `run.` files. Not any BitBake variables. I see `CFLAGS` and `RANLIB` and things like that; I don't see `WORKDIR`, or `S`, or `FILESEXTRAPATHS` or whatever.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I presume you've discovered `bitbake -e`, right?  That dumps the environment specific to a single bitbake "target" (ie. a recipe.)  I believe `FILESPATH` is the key variable that bitbake uses to find files specified in a `file://` `SRC_URI` component.  Using `bitbake -e (recipe) | grep ^FILESPATH=` will display that very large path variable!

I don't know of a way to track assignments to that variable, but there are several ways to modify it. (Actually I recall a bitbake patch which would annotate the output of `bitbake -e` with what file modified which variable but can't recall the details. Ask on the oe list.) In any case, if you remove the `=` sign from the grep above you can see the other ways `FILESPATH` can be modified.  I think this is covered in the various docs, as well.

Finally, you may have better luck asking on the [openembedded mailing list](https://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Mailing_lists), rather than here on stackoverflow.

`bitbake -e` and the log files (found in `${WORKDIR}/temp`) are your best debug tools. (Also check out `ack-grep`. Better than `grep` for some bitbake-related use cases.) Where is `WORKDIR` you ask?

```
bitbake -e (recipe) | grep ^WORKDIR=
```

Once you get familiar with `WORKDIR`, you'll see the pattern and won't have to find it that way.

Happy baking! ;)

Comment: Yes, I'm using -e to view the results. But the results between two of my recipes differ, and I cannot see why in the dumped environment.

Comment: I somehow missed, that you mentioned the "WORKDIR/temp" folder in your answer. Discovering the "temp" folder has been a real eye-opener for me, and has greatly improved my success-rate with bitbake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Toaster, in interactive mode. In the configuration page, you can track variable assignment history.

The mockup is here: https://www.yoctoproject.org/toaster/build-configuration.html

To use it, run "source toaster start" after "source oe-init-build-env" and in the web interface you will find data logged from your builds.

Hope this helps,
Alex

Answer (score -2):

Turns out, that there is a patch for doing this in later versions of BitBake, its just not supported in the one I'm currently using :-(

Comment: Hi, S.C., Can you be specific which patch and how you use it? I'm looking for the same solution.

Comment: @minghua I'm sorry but I've forgotten where I found the patch. Found via Google searching for clues to debugging bitbake.